# Equality and inequality constraints in multi-objective optimisation?

Tags: optimization, mathematical-optimization

This question has been posted in stach mathematics [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3021952/equality-and-inequality-constraints-in-multi-objective-optimisation)  and I would like to post it here as well to get an answer

The general form of the multi-objective optimisation as the following:

```
Maximise/ Minimise     f(x),              m=1,2,… ,M;
          subject to   j (x)≥0,             j=1,2,… ,J;
                       k (x)=0,             k=1,2,… ,K;
                       x_i^((L))≤x_i≤x_i^((U)),   i=1,2,… ,N;
```

where, `f(x): R^N→R^M,x=(x_1,x_2,...,x_K,...,x_N)` is the vector of the N parameters, M is the number of objective functions, k and j are the equality and inequality constraints, respectively, with K and J are the number of equality and inequality constraints that the solution must satisfy, respectively. The last set of constraints are the parameter bounds restricting each parameter `x_i` to take a value within an upper bound `x_i^((U))` and a lower bound `x_i^((L))`.

What does the equality and inequality constraints? and what do they do? and how can i know the K and J?

I appreciate all the feedback

Comment: K and J are just the number of equality and inequality constraints. They are usually directly related to the problem you want to solve.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen Thank you for your answer, but for more clarrification, if I said x_i=<5 reject the value of the optimiser this will be inequality constraint for any number less or equal to 5, other wise it will be equality constraint for any value bigger than 5? Am I right?

Comment: No, that statement does not make sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

An optimization problem is a way of modeling a system.  Variables, objectives and constraints all come out of that model.  Consider a constraint on how much of a resource `x_i` is available.  Suppose you have 5 of whatever `x_i` is.  Then an inequality constraint `j` is `-x_i + 5 >= 0` .  Equality constraints K come from similar considerations.  Suppose you must assign exactly three of `x_i`.  Then you have an equality constraint `k`: `x_i = 3`.

Comment: Incidentally, I think cross-posting is frowned upon and this is more a mathematical programming question than it is a computer programming one.  But I do know the answer :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but for more clarrification, if I said `x_i=<5` reject the value of the optimiser this will be inequality constraint for any number less or equal to 5, other wise it will be equality constraint for any value bigger than 5? Am I right?

Comment: Not exactly, what it means is that the value of `x_i` must be less than or equal to five.  No value of `x_i` greater than 5 is considered feasible.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, if you want to describe it to a non specialist using simple words, would you please do that?